# Can't do integer == comparison

Tags: ios, if-statement

So I have a method that sets an integer: `-(void)setcurrentviewfromint:(int)currentint{` It is in a class called `MyView`. From my `viewDidLoad` method, I call it, and set it too 1:
`currentview` is of type int, created in my header file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyView *myview = [[MyView alloc]init];
    [myview setcurrentviewfromint:1];
}
```

Then, in `MyView.m`, I have these classes:

```
-(void)setcurrentviewfromint:(int)currentint{
    currentview = currentint;
    NSLog("currentviewis:%d",currentview);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"drawRectCalled");
    if (currentview == 1) {
        NSLog(@"do something here");
        }
    }

}
```

But the debugger prints out:

```
2012-07-18 18:02:44.211 animation[76135:f803] currentviewis:1
2012-07-18 18:02:44.223 animation[76135:f803] drawRectCalled
```

But doesn't print "do something here". Any ideas why `currentview` doesn't equal 1?

Comment: "But the compiler prints out" ... are you sure that's coming from the compiler?

Comment: Is it possible you have a multithreading issue? Where else are you setting the value for `currentView`?

Comment: I don't see your "currentviewis:1" message.  (That is, the "1" message that's printed first, doesn't match what you supposedly printed in setcurrentviewfromint:.)  Are you sure `viewDidLoad` is actually called?

Comment: Sorry my bad i changed my code while copying im editing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, about your question. 
What datatype is currentview?
Second, it looks like your NSLog in setcurrentviewfromint: never gets called. If it was called, youd see "currentviewis:1" so make sure that is linking up correctly.

And, I must say, camel-case! Your method names are all lowercase and it's hard to read. :)

Comment: +1 for camel casing.  For the OP's reference, camel casing means that variables and method names should begin with a lowercase letter, and then the first letter of all subsequent words should be capitalized.  For example: `myShinyVariable` `thatOtherVariableHere` `thisCoolMethodIJustWrote`.

Comment: Yeah my bad. In my code, i changed it. My compiler output didn't exactly match up, because i changed my code when i added it to the question, to be clearer. But i messed up on the debugger code.

Comment: Thank you You were right. the problem was i was allocating it like a variable. What i had to do was add an iboutlet too it, and a @class MyView

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the MYView you are setting is not the one you are reading currentView from.

In viewDidLoad you are creating a local variable myView and then setting its current view and then this myView becomes a memory leak as nothing points to it.

Assuming that MyView is the class the viewDidLoad is on and that currentview is an int attribute of that class (although the why is the method not setcurrentview:) . I would expect the code to be more like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setcurrentviewfromint:1];
}
```

Thus setting the current view in itself

And as others state please use the Objective C standard of CamelCase

Comment: Its not, the view did load is in my ViewController.h. and sorry for the camelcase issue. I taught myself, and never learned/understood why or when to use it. But that is something i should learn

Comment: @EliHulse where is a pointer to a MyView stored? If in the nib then you should not alloc another

Comment: MyView is a subclass of UIView, and is the custom class of a view in my ViewController.xib.

Comment: @EliHulse - put those details into the question as it makes it possible to answer - when done I will delete ths answer as it is wrong - my other comment here os the issue

Comment: Just follow the advice on writing good questions and give all the information so others don't have to make guesses which are wrong in this case.

Comment: do i have to, even though i figured it out?

Comment: im pretty sure since the problem wasnt the problem i thought it was, there is already a thread answering it